# adding a Post To Facebook Timeline from iOS APP

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, api, post

HI Im trying to enable a IBAction to post on an user's timeline while they have an active section. I am getting an error message stating; Implicit declaration of function "x" is invalid C99. I been reading posts about the issue but no luck and honestly I am not sure if I am doing this right at all. I updated the permissions on my fb app and got the object code from the Graph API Explorer but I dont know if Im implementing it right on my code.

Here is my post method:

```
-(void) aPost
{
    NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *object =
    [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"website"
                                            title:@"CR Taxi APP"
                                            image:@"http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/047/Purple4/v4/05/cc/f2/05ccf23f-a409-1e73-a649-a5e6afc4e6eb/mzl.llffzfbp.175x175-75.jpg"
                                              url:@"https://itunes.apple.com/cr/app/cr-taxi/id674226640?mt=8"
                                      description:@"La nueva aplicación para llamar taxis!"];;

    [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"{id_from_create_call}"
                                       graphObject:object
                                 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                     id result,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                                     // handle the result
                                 }];

}
```

and this is my action method

```
- (IBAction)publishAction:(id)sender {

    if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions
         indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {

        NSArray *writepermissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                     @"publish_stream",
                                     @"publish_actions",
                                     nil];


        [[FBSession activeSession]requestNewPublishPermissions:writepermissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends completionHandler:^(FBSession *aSession, NSError *error){
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error on public permissions: %@", error);
            }
            else {
             **not on the code //( error on this one)   aPost(aSession, error);
            }


        }];

    }
    else {
        // If permissions present, publish the story
     **not on the code //(not an error on this one)  aPost(FBSession.activeSession, nil);
    }


}
```

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the compiler error is actually "Implicit declaration of function 'aPost' is invalid C99", although the formatting of your action method code is wonky as written. The compiler is only going to produce that error message the first time it encounters the function call to aPost.

aPost is written as a method that has no return and takes no arguments. You are trying to call it as a C function, passing it two arguments, which the compiler interprets as an entirely new function. As aPost is written with all the hard-coded strings, you probably just want to change the calls to aPost(arg1, arg2); to [self aPost]; (provided aPost and publishAction are in the same class).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: might helps you

//Write This Line in your ViewController.h File

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *postParams;
```

//in View Controller.m File

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
     self.postParams =
     [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"], @"picture",
 @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
 @"build apps.", @"caption",
 @"testing for my app.", @"description",
 nil];

[self.postParams setObject:@"hgshsghhgsls" forKey:@"message"];

 }
 - (IBAction)SharePressed:(id)sender {

 @try {


    [self openSession];
    NSArray *permissions =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream",@"manage_friendlists",@"read_stream", nil];

       [[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                               completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                   /* handle success + failure in block */
                                                   if (![session isOpen]) {
                                                       [self openSession];
                                                   }
                                               }];

    [FBRequestConnection   startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:self.postParams HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                            completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id result,NSError *error) {
                                NSString *alertText;
                                if (error) {                                               
                                  alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"error: domain = %@, code = %d, des = %@",error.domain, error.code,error.description];  
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    alertText=@"Uploaded Successfully";
                                    [self ResetAllcontent];
                                }
                                // Show the result in an alert
                                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result" message:alertText delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
                            }]; 





}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Login" message:@"For Sharing on facbook please login with facbook" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
@finally {
}
}

- (void)openSession
 {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,
   FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
 }];

ACAccountStore *accountStore;
ACAccountType *accountTypeFB;
if ((accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init]) &&
    (accountTypeFB = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook] ) ){

    NSArray *fbAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountTypeFB];
    id account;
    if (fbAccounts && [fbAccounts count] > 0 &&
        (account = [fbAccounts objectAtIndex:0])){

        [accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:account completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error) {
            //we don't actually need to inspect renewResult or error.
            if (error){

            }
        }];
    }
}
}
}
```

//=====in your plist file do
URLTypes=>Item 0=> URL Schemes =>Item 0=>fbyourfacebookId

FacebookAppID-your facebookID

[image]
And yes dont forget to create facebook id at developer.facebook.com
and also give permissions as your need

Comment: Hi Chitra, Thank you for answering my question although I tried it and just got a bunch of other errors.. starting with postParams Im really new to this whole facebook posting... Is there any way you could explain in more detail what I need to do? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: did you added facebook id in plist file? OR Do i need to show it with steps?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)shareViaFacebook:(id)sender {


if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.  Join on Linute.",self.userNameLabel.text], @"name",
                                   //@"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                                   locationString, @"description",
                                   //@"http://www.linute.com/", @"link",
                                   eventPicString, @"picture",//imageURL
                                   nil];

    // Make the request
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              if (!error) {
                                  // Link posted successfully to Facebook
                                  NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
                              } else {
                                  // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                  // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                  NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                              }
                          }];
}else{

    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email",@"user_friends",@"publish_actions"]];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];

    [session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

        if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

            [self shareViaFacebook:nil];

        }else{
            [self shareViaFacebook:nil];


        }
    }];
}
```